# iostat am I okay?

Tags: iostat

This is the result of iostat

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          13.65    0.00    9.98    3.86    2.22   70.29

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            0.00     9.00    0.00   14.40     0.00   140.00    19.44    27.48 5991.25  46.32  66.70
xvdap2            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.19    0.00    3.93    6.69    0.03   85.15

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            0.00     3.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    19.08    0.00   0.00  45.44
xvdap2            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

iostat await sucks time is 7000. Does that mean process need to wait for 7 seconds before writing?

Comment: just so we are on the same page, you are talking about the 5.9 seconds, not 7, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At least one process has waited for 5.9s. I saw the same thing (5.3 seconds). It seemed to be a broken fibrechannel path that was not detected as broken; it worked (aka the symptom went away) after disabling one port on the fibrechannel switch: https://serverfault.com/questions/575447/server-hangs-randomly-without-log-entries